# Get page's immediate siblings in PHP

Tags: php, html, magento, foreach

I am predominantly a front-end developer currently working in Magento. As with all things Magento there does not seem to be a simple method to retrieve the current pages immediate siblings.

To do this I am first ascertaining which page I am on by ID.

Then I am using a for loop to determine the position of this element by evaluating the ID in the list of children from the parent page.

Once i have the position I re-run the loop to grab the sibling before the current (i - 1) or after the current position (i + 1).

This feels really dirty and over engineered and I know there is a more elegant method to produce the same result, I just need a point in the right direction.

NOTE: I am extending the following module with the code listed below http://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-cms-tree.html

Code is as follows:

```
public function getSiblingsNav($parentID, $currentPageID) {

    $parentPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($parentID);
    $activePages = $parentPage->getChildren()->addActiveFilter();
    $html = '';
    if ($activePages->count() > 0) {
        $html .= '<ul class="siblings">';
        foreach ($activePages as $page) {
        $i++;
        if ($currentPageID == $page->getId()) {
               $position = $i;      
            }
        }
        foreach ($activePages as $page) {
            $location++;
            if ($location == $position + 1 || $location == $position - 1) {
                $html .= '<li class="' . ($location == $position + 1 ? 'next' : 'previous') . '"><a class="button" href="' . $page->getUrl() . '">';
                $html .= $page->getTitle();
                $html .= '</a></li>';               
            }
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
        } else {
           return false;
       }  
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you wanna try mysql limit function with collection. To get previous page, like 'id < current-page-id order by id desc limit 1' and to get next 'id > current-page-id order by id asc limit 1'

Comment: Ah yeah, I hadn't thought of that. Will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmsParentId = 13;

$parentNode = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('page_id', $cmsParentId)
    ->getFirstItem();

$children = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_node_id', $parentNode->getId());

$children->getSelect()->order('sort_order');

$html = '';

if ($children->getSize()) {
    $html = '<ul class="siblings">';
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $html .= '<li>Node ID: ' . $child->getId()
            . '<br />Page ID: ' . $child->getPageId()
            . '<br />Identifier: ' . $child->getIdentifier()
            . '<br />Position: ' . $child->getSortOrder()
            . '<br />Path: ' . $child->getRequestUrl() . '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There are a few methods you  used that I was unaware of. This appears to be returning all of the children. In my case I am only wanting to return the next and previous siblings of the current page. Does that make sense?